# Join groupby column with a comma in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id_sin':['s123','s123','s124','s124'],
                       'raison':['first problem','second problem','album','dog']
    })
>>> df
  id_sin          raison
0   s123   first problem
1   s123  second problem
2   s124           album
3   s124             dog
```

This is the expected output:

```
  id_sin                         raison
0   s123  first problem, second problem
1   s124                     album, dog
```

What I tried:

```
df['raison'] = df.groupby('id_sin')['raison'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

But doesn't work... what am I missing? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `agg`:

```
df.groupby('id_sin')['raison'].agg(', '.join).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  id_sin                         raison
0   s123  first problem, second problem
1   s124                     album, dog
```

Comment: sorry, accident mouse click. Darn, i need a new mouse.

Comment: Thank you man, I didn't know `.agg` also has this... amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the groups to lists:

```
df.groupby(['id_sin']).raison.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(x)))
```

After testing your code, it turns out that you should not do `df['raison'] =...` because `df.groupby('id_sin')['raison'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))` has length 2 with different index than `df`, which has length 4.