# Pandas aggregate data by same ID and comma separate values in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have data such as the following:

| ID | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Finance |
| 2 | Computer Science |
| 3 | Data Science |
| 1 | Marketing |
| 2 | Finance |

My goal is to aggregate the common ID's into one row and add the differing categories all into one column seperate by commas, such as the following:

| ID | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Finance, Marketing |
| 2 | Computer Science , Finance |
| 3 | Data Science |

How would I go about this using Pandas?

Edit:
I also have other columns for the ID's I would like to keep. For example:

| ID | Category | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Finance | New York |
| 2 | Computer Science | Los Angeles |
| 3 | Data Science | Austin |
| 1 | Marketing | New York |
| 2 | Finance | Los Angeles |

since the additional data from the other columns are the same for all similarr ID's (ex: ID 1 has the same location for all instances, as does ID 2) I would like to not drop any columns and keep other data like this:

| ID | Category | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Finance, Marketing | New York |
| 2 | Computer Science , Finance | Los Angeles |
| 3 | Data Science | Austin |

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')['Category'].agg(','.join)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join groupby column with a comma in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697144/join-groupby-column-with-a-comma-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you for the response, it does for the category column and in terms of combining the ID column, but all the other columns are of data are dropped when I use this, and I would like to keep them, but I'm not sure how

Comment: When grouping data you need to provide an aggregation method for every column you wish to keep - could you update your question to specify what the other columns are in your input data and how they should appear in your result?

Comment: I have columns such as Location, Building Number, School URL that are the same for  all similar ID's (ex: all locations for all instances of ID 1 are the same, same goes for ID 2, ID3), the only column that had differing data among same ID's was the category column, when i combined the common ID's into one row, I would like to keep the other columns in that row

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset (as code or file) from which you generated the dataframe. This will help us code the answer.